# JQuery How to get JSON result?

Tags: jquery, rest, jax-rs

A Beginner's question:
Here's my server side code, very simple:

```
    @GET
    @Path("/query")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Map<Integer,String> getUsers(
        @QueryParam("from") int from,
        @QueryParam("to") int to) {

        Map<Integer, String> orders = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
        orders.put(1, "order1");
        orders.put(2, "order2");
        orders.put(3, "order3");

        return orders;

    }
```

Here's my JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#id1').mouseover(function() {

       alert("ok");
       var formData = {from:3, to:2};
        var result = $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/MyJSON/resources/entities.customer/query',
            type: "GET",
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {alert(data);}
        });                 
  }); 

}); // end ready
```

How do I parse the data object and get the json, which is `{"1":"order1","2":"order2","3":"order3"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
success: function (data) {
 alert(data['1']);  // output: order1
 alert(data['2']);  // output: order2
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/cjh8h/1/)**

Using jQuery `$.each()` loop:

```
success: function (data) {
  $.each(data, function(key, val) { // here key = 1, 2, 3...
      alert(val); // output: order1, order2...
  });
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/aAVKK/)**

Using vanilla javascript loop

```
for(var key in data) {
    // key = 1, 2, 3...
    alert(data[key]); // output: order1, order2...
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/Zu3QV/1/)**

#### NOTE

As you set `dataType: 'json'` is ajax config, so you don't need any extra parsing effort like `$.parseJSON()` or `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: Wow thanks. it works now! :). So if I use .getJSON instead of .ajax, do i need to parse the object and how?